# Sequential Files execution

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have a **master.bat** file, which contains:

```
call file1.bat
call file2.bat
```

I want **file2.bat** should not start run until **file1.bat** completes its execution and generates the output, but in my case **file2.bat** runs without waiting for **file1.bat** to complete its execution.

Execution time of files are as follows:

```
file1.bat= 70 sec
file3.bat= 20 sec
```

**EDIT1**

Contents of both batch files are:

**file1.bat**

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SET "keystring1="
(
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
Source.txt
 ) DO (
ECHO %%a|FIND "Appprocess.exe" >NUL
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 SET keystring1=%%a
FOR %%b IN (App1 App2 App3 App4 App5 App6 ) DO (
ECHO %%a|FIND "%%b" >NUL
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 IF DEFINED keystring1 CALL ECHO(%%keystring1%% %%b&SET   "keystring1="

)))>result.txt

GOTO :EOF
```

**file2.bat**

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

(for /f "tokens=1,2" %%a in (memory.txt) do (
for /f "tokens=5" %%c in ('find " %%a " ^< result.txt ') do echo %%c %%b
))> new.txt
```

Comment: call file2.bat at the end of file1.bat and similary call file3.bat at the end of the file2.bat.

Comment: thats what i am doing in **Master.bat** using **call** function, which is used for same purpose..or I didn't get you Sumit..could you pls explain more..?

Comment: No I meant, instead of calling file2.bat from master.bat call it from file1.bat if it is allowed in your application architecture; Because when you are calling the files from the master.bat it is a single command for it, so master.bat is first executing the first command which eventually calls the file1.bat and after executing the first command it moves to second command which eventually calls file2.bat irrespective of what results in executing the first command in this case.

Comment: @sumitb..is it possible to insert above mentioned execution time, as waiting time in **master.bat** in between files..because i can't call file2.bat from file1.bat due to some reason..:)

Comment: It's running file3.bat because something in file2.bat is multi-threaded.  Shows us file2.bat in your question, if you want help.

Comment: STOP EDITING YOUR QUESTIONS AND CHANGING THE QUESTION

Comment: @foxidrive..i didn't change the question just removed extra **file.bat** for better visibility..anyway my Apologies..!..yes I have added batch files content above.

Comment: Your question earlier said `file3` was running to quickly.  Now it says `file2` was running too quickly.  **and** you posted another completely new question on the same issue.  @Aacini wrote in another question of yours that you also changed the question there.

Comment: Yes..Foxi..i did..but my intention was just to gather all tried options at a place..I am really sorry for this.!

Comment: If you **add** information to clarify the issue then the answers remain relevant.  Otherwise it is a confusing mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running another bat / cmd script using "call" actually does wait for that process to finish before going to the next statement. So, there is something else going on within your "file2.bat", or whatever it calls, that is allowing part of that process to continue while the main process believes file2.bat has completed.

You could try using the "Start" command which lets you specify whether or not to wait until whatever you "start" finishes before moving to the next line. By default it goes to the next line without waiting for its process to complete, but you can specify "/wait" and it will not continue until its process has finished. Type "help start" at the DOS / Command prompt for details.

Note: it is *usually* best to use the "cmd" extension on scripts instead of "bat" as "cmd" scripts always run in a 32-bit space but "bat" scripts sometime run in a 16-bit space.

Comment: @Srutzky..yes..file2.bat has a loop search which usually takes around 60 sec to complete its execution and writing the result in output.txt file..i just want that file3.bat should wait till file2.bat completely finishes its execution...In windows 7, **call** command is working fine for file2.bat..but in Windows server 2008 R2..its not waiting for file2.bat execution completion..:(

Comment: I tried **start /wait** method for **file1.txt**..but not working..pls see **EDIT1** in question.

Comment: @Sunny, 1) why are you using "setlocal enabledelayedexpansion"? I don't think you need it. 2) The ECHO syntax in file1.bat looks wrong: there is a left-paren with no matching right paren, and 3) on Windows Server 2008R2, does file2.bat (well, in your posted example it is now file1.bat) ever complete with the correct data in result.txt?

Comment: @srutzky..yeah got the error, your point 3 leads me to the error point..actually source.txt was getting updated while file1.bat started to call it..i added a 20sec **ping** delay between source.txt creation and file1.bat calling..and thus it resolved the issue completely..thanks..!! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
REM File1.bat
REM DO YOUR FILE STUFF

Call file2.bat
```

and then

```
REM File2.bat
REM DO YOUR FILE STUFF

Call file3.bat
```

and theenn

```
REM File3.bat
REM DO YOUR FILE STUFF
REM Done? or call next file to run
```

Comment: @Psycho..I tried this method..but still not working..pls see **EDIT1** in question.